# Are questions about managing virtual personae on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

In [this question on Meta SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/619/on-which-trilogy-site-does-a-meta-computing-question-belong?rq=1) the OP wonders if his SuperUser question on [Best Practices for managing virtual personae](https://superuser.com/questions/29177/best-practices-for-managing-virtual-personae) is in the right place.

I was wondering: would the question be on topic on the main site here?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I wouldn't think so.  That's really more of a branding question, not how to manage a community.  If you were managing a fan club or something then maybe, but reputation management doesn't seem like it would be a good fit here.